# WinForms WebBrowser Control and image relative path error

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a [Winform Textbox](http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/) for editing an HTML fragment and the project uses a Winforms WebBrowser control. If my HTML `img` tag's `src` attribute uses a relative path for example `src="../cat_images/VOD/VOD_logo_small_2.jpg"`, it will turn into `src="about:../cat_images/VOD/VOD_logo_small_2.jpg"`

How do I get rid of `about:`?

Should I just write a method to filter out `about:`, or is there a setting in the WebBrowser control that can be used to disable it? The WebBrowser control also adds an additional return carriage and line feed. Is there a way to disable this?

```
this.htmDisplay.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.chemicalMasterBindingSource, "CatalogDesc", true));
        this.htmDisplay.Fonts = new string[] {
    "Corbel",
    "Corbel, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
    "Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif",
    "Consolas, Courier New, Courier, monospace"};
        this.htmDisplay.IllegalPatterns = new string[] {
    "<script.*?>",
    "<\\w+\\s+.*?(j|java|vb|ecma)script:.*?>",
    "<\\w+(\\s+|\\s+.*?\\s+)on\\w+\\s*=.+?>",
    "</?input.*?>"};
        this.htmDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(92, 126);
        this.htmDisplay.Name = "htmDisplay";
        this.htmDisplay.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1);
        this.htmDisplay.ShowHtmlSource = true;
        this.htmDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 245);
        this.htmDisplay.TabIndex = 149;
        this.htmDisplay.ToolbarStyle = GvS.Controls.ToolbarStyles.AlwaysInternal;
```

Comment: You can use the string.Replace() method and replace the "about:" with ""

Comment: Jack can you also show the current code you are using in regards to your question..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I just updated my post with the code in Winforms. It is basically just setting.

Comment: While this is shameless self-promotion, you could try [my control instead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43954/ZetaHtmlEditControl). I have functions for dealing with images and the control uses an internal web server to get rid of loading HTML through the file:// protocol. This version also works with IE9+.